# SymbolName applied to a list of variables, some of which may have values assigned

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica:

I would like to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.

I would like to print the name of each argument.  The problem is that SymbolName evaluates its input.  For a given variable, you can get around this:

```
a=18;
SymbolName[Unevaluated[a]]
```

works.  But that won't work if the variable is in a list.  For example:

```
printname[x__]:=Print[Table[SymbolName[Unevaluated[{x}[[i]]]],{i,1,Length[{x}]}]];
printname[a,b,c]
```

will not work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and also format your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica tries to evaluate the argument of `Unevaluated[]` when you call it. So `{x}[[i]]` gets converted into `{18, b, c}[[i]]` which you didn't want and then the iteration over `i` doesn't work anymore because `Unevaluated[]` doesn't let the `Table` access the iterator.

So, to really solve the issue you should disable Mathematica's evaluation completely for the functions that you want to pass the symbols through.

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[SymbolName, HoldAll];
        SetAttributes[Map, HoldAll];
```

After this you can just do

```
In[2]:= a=18; SymbolName @@@ Unevaluated /@ {a, b, c}
Out[2]:= {a, b, c}
```

where `@@@` and `/@` are shorthand for `Apply[]` and `Map[]`.

Setting `Hold[]` or similar attributes in Mathematica's built in functions can lead to trouble. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/when-should-i-and-when-should-i-not-set-the-holdall-attribute-on-a-function-i/4127#4127) question and answer in the Mathematica stackexchange for more information.

Specifically, to make a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments would be

```
sym = SymbolName @@@ Unevaluated /@ {##} &
```

But the `List[]` function that takes the sequence of arguments `##` for the function `&` will again evaluate `a` and turning `HoldAll` on for `List[]` is not OK.

Thus the easiest way to do this is to define a function with `HoldAll` that just passes the args into a `Block[]` as the list of local variables. This makes a creates an isolated context where the variables do not evaluate to anything.

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
In[2]:= f[seq__] := Block[{seq}, Print[SymbolName /@ {seq}]];
In[3]:= a=18; f[a, b, c]
Out[3]:= {a, b, c}
```

Comment: Timo, I am not sure what happened and why I did not follow up earlier, but  thank you belatedly for your answer.