# How to get the names of symbols as a list of strings?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, tostring

I can get the name of an individual symbol:

```
ts[s_]:=ToString[Unevaluated[s]];
SetAttributes[ts,HoldAll]
```

This seems to work

```
ss=5;
InputForm[ts[ss]]
```

gives

```
"ss"
```

Now I want to map this to a list of symbols, which does not work, because I cannot suppress the evaluation of ss:

```
InputForm[ts[#] & /@ {aa, ss}]
```

gives

```
{"aa", "5"}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you very much.

Comment: `StringSplit[StringReplace[ts[{aa, ss}], {"{"->"", "}"->"", " "->""}], ","]` returns `{"aa","ss"}`

Comment: Thank you @Bill. That is a clever use of the string manipulation to achieve the desired result.  I had a look at the answer to a related question I asked some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040972/symbolname-applied-to-a-list-of-variables-some-of-which-may-have-values-assigne). Based on that answer, I have another approach as follows: `ts[seq_List] := Block[seq, ToString /@ seq ]; ts[seq__] := Block[{seq}, ToString /@ {seq} ];` This will allow ts to accept either a single list of symbols or several symbols as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ts[s_] := ToString[Unevaluated[s]]
SetAttributes[ts, HoldAll]
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};
Map[ts, Unevaluated[{a, b, c}]]
```

> {a, b, c}

You could also use `ts[s_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]]`

Comment: Thank you @Chris.  If I add the definition `ts[s_List]:=ts/@Unevaluated[s]`, that allows me to define a function that accepts either a single symbol or a list of symbol names as an argument, without having to wrap it in Unevaluated.  The trick that you pointed out is to get the Unevaluated wrapped around the list before passing to Map.  Thanks!

Comment: you have motivated an even simpler solution.  If I just make ts Listable, the Map will be automatic, and the Unevaluated is already there for the argument, hence `ts[s_]:=ToString[Unevaluated[s]];SetAttributes[ts,{HoldAll,Listable}]`  That seems to work.  Thanks again.